# Inserts a new sheet only instead of a Pivot Table in a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automatically insert the Pivot table in new sheet. When I run this, it only inserts a new sheet with the name of Pivot table, however it does not create the Pivot cache and it's not reading the data from source sheet. The sheet name is `Data` and `Pivot` should be created from this.

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
        (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
        CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
        TableName:="PivotTable")

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
        (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Last_Touch_User_Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Action_Code")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Result_Code")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Medical_Manager__")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlCount
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit you post. Copy and paste the code directly from your VBE and format it as code, not as blockquote. I tried to clean it up, but I don't want to spend the time.

Comment: I'll second @teylyn. I did most of it, but be sure to clean up your code next time. It is easy. In VBE (where you write your code, highlight it and press `Tab` Then copy it here. It will automatically format your code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You look like you have tried to combine or partially separate out steps here:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
        (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
        CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
        TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

When in fact you want (as per your variables) to have two completely separate steps for the creation of the cache and then the pivottable:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
        (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

And watch out for `On Error Resume Next` that isn't closed with an `On Error Goto O`, which is probably why you didn't spot this.

Always add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to check for variable declarations, spellings etc.